# Big multiplexer with for loop in Verilog

Tags: for-loop, switch-statement, verilog, synthesis

I want my circuit to write a value between 0<sub>10</sub> and 255<sub>10</sub> to a reg called `mem_address_reg` depending on an incoming address. After an and-operation this address can take one of 256<sub>10</sub> different values. I want the circuit to be combinational, so one way to check the value is to build a multiplexer with 256<sub>10</sub> different inputs that then writes one of those to the output, depending on the incoming address (the select line of the multiplexer).

This circuit works but requires me to write a script that generates all 256<sub>10</sub> case-statements and the code gets bloated. So instead of writing each and every line myself I want to use a for loop that generates those for me. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

What did I do wrong?

The working circuit with bloated code:

```
wire [31:0] masked_write_adr;
reg  [29:0] nvmm_write_request_adr;
reg  [7:0]  mem_address_reg;     

assign masked_write_adr = {2'b00, nvmm_write_request_adr} & 32'hFFC0_0000;

always@(*)
begin
    case(masked_write_adr)
      32'h0000_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'h00;
      32'h0040_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'h01;
      32'h0080_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'h02;
      32'h00C0_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'h03;
      32'h0100_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'h04;
      32'h0140_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'h05;
      (...)
      32'h3FC0_0000:  mem_address_reg = 8'hFF;
      default:        mem_address_reg = 8'h0;
    endcase
end
```

This is what I thought to be an analog circuit which does not work:

```
wire [31:0] masked_write_adr;
reg  [29:0] nvmm_write_request_adr;
reg  [7:0]  mem_address_reg;     

assign masked_write_adr = {2'b00, nvmm_write_request_adr} & 32'hFFC0_0000;

integer k;
always@(*)
begin
  mem_address_reg <= 8'h00;
  for(k=0; k<255; k=k+1)
  begin
      if((k*32'h40_0000) == masked_write_adr)
        mem_address_reg <= k;
  end              
end
```

Comment: @toolic Wouldn't the for loop infer some kind of multiplexer? For every possible value of `masked_write_adr` there is one defined output for `mem_address_reg`. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how for loops work in Verilog; how is the second solution not conceptually analog the first one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just do

```
assign mem_address_reg = masked_write_addr[29:22];
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution, thank you! I don't know why I didn't come up with this myself. Could you also explain how the two solutions infer different circuit designs to fully answer this question?

Comment: I think its just a matter of how much effort is put into optimization. The two solutions are functionally equivalent.